Sumar totales de 3 tablas en Power BI
Necesito sumar el total que ya esta calculado en tres tablas , puedo hacerlo con sumando los tres datos y mostrar el resultado en una variable? o debo hacer una tabla con las coloumnas totales? gracias de antemano
